# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I had some code for a thread pool that has been working on my Ubuntu machine for quite some time. The project is a CMake project, and I believe it was using a recent version of g++ as the compiler.

I just tried to run the code on a Mac, CMake tries to use AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032, and I'm hit with

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument
```

Is AppleClang missing `std::shared_mutex` or `std::mutex`? These are c++17 features. Is there something I need to do to enable c++17 on this Mac? I do mention that it is required in my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Here is the full build output:

```
(base) clare.obrien.brown@Clares-Air build % cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/clare.obrien.brown/ssme/build
(base) clare.obrien.brown@Clares-Air build % make
Scanning dependencies of target ssme_test
[ 16%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/ssme_test.dir/test-main.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/ssme_test.dir/test_ada_pmmh_mvn.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/ssme_test.dir/test_parameters.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/clare.obrien.brown/ssme/test/test_parameters.cpp:5:
/Users/clare.obrien.brown/ssme/include/ssme/parameters.h:333:58: warning: unused parameter 'trans_p' [-Wunused-parameter]
float_t null_trans<float_t>::log_jacobian(const float_t& trans_p)
                                                         ^
1 warning generated.
[ 66%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/ssme_test.dir/test_thread_pool.cpp.o
/Users/clare.obrien.brown/ssme/test/test_thread_pool.cpp:13:46: warning: unused parameter 'obs_data' [-Wunused-parameter]
    static double d(param_t nums, obs_data_t obs_data) {
                                             ^
/Users/clare.obrien.brown/ssme/test/test_thread_pool.cpp:54:45: warning: unused parameter 'od' [-Wunused-parameter]
                [](param_t nums, obs_data_t od) -> double{
                                            ^
/Users/clare.obrien.brown/ssme/test/test_thread_pool.cpp:82:40: warning: unused parameter 'ydata' [-Wunused-parameter]
    double d(param_t theta, obs_data_t ydata) {
                                       ^
3 warnings generated.
[ 83%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/ssme_test.dir/test_utils.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ssme_test
[100%] Built target ssme_test
(base) clare.obrien.brown@Clares-Air build % cd ../test 
(base) clare.obrien.brown@Clares-Air test % ../build/test/ssme_test 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument
zsh: abort      ../build/test/ssme_test
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is where that exception is being thrown from: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/src/mutex.cpp#L35

This typically happens when `.lock()` is called on a `mutex` that is not yet constructed, or has already been destructed.  This can happen for mutexes with static storage duration when they are accessed prior to `main()`, or after `main()` returns.  You'll need to review your start up or shutdown logic to ensure that the lifetime of the `mutex` exceeds the lifetime of the clients trying to use it.

/Applications/Utilities/Console.app can provide you with a stack trace of the application when the uncaught exception was thrown.  This may aid in your debugging efforts.  Compiling with `-g` may provide better debug info for the stack trace.

Comment: It's the destructor of my thread pool, but I can't figure out how that would be possible, because it owns everything. When the destructor happens, everything goes poof. Let me play around with the order in which data members are declared

Comment: Your final sentence was going to be my first suggestion. :-)  Members are destructed in reverse order of their declaration.

Comment: oo there it goes. it works! thank you very much for your help

Comment: [From CppRef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex): Because the default constructor is `constexpr`, static mutexes are initialized as part of [static non-local initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables), before any dynamic non-local initialization begins. **This makes it safe to lock a mutex in a constructor of any static object.** (but seems pretty unsafe in Apple's `iOS` and `MacOS`, even if locked from non-static context)

Comment: what do you mean : but seems pretty unsafe in Apple's iOS and MacOS, even if locked from non-static context, is there any reference

Answer (score 3):

I had this crash error after some button clicks when my phone is connected to Xcode. After unplugging the phone from the computer, pressing the same buttons didn't cause any crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error due to a duplicated import - I eliminated one and it started working.